# Is there a CSS selector for first level of nested elements without going deeper?

Tags: javascript, css, extjs

```
<div id="owner">
  <!-- ...other parent elements -->
    <div class="parent one">                <!-- parent lvl 1 -->
      <div class="child one">               <!-- child lvl 1 -->
        <!-- ...other parent elements -->
          <div class="parent two">            <!-- parent lvl 2 -->
            <div class="child two"></div>     <!-- child lvl 2 -->
            <div class="child two"></div>
            <div class="child two"></div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="child one"></div> 
      <div class="child one"></div> 
      <div class="child one"></div> 
    </div>
</div>

var el = document.getElementById("owner");
el && el.querySelectorAll('.parent .child');
```

**Important:** class name "one" and "two" is only for visual purposes - it does not exist.


In result we will get 7 times div.child nodes.
How to create selector that only selects children from the "first lvl" (we end up with 4 x div.child.one).


**Important:** this is simple example but in real on we do not know how deep div.parent.one is in div#owner and the same applies to div.parent.two 


Maybe it is possible with **ExtJS** ?

```
var el = Ext.get('#owner');
el.down('.parent .child');     //does not work, returns all elements as above
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/56n2jdz8/18/)

Comment: What is expected result? Are you trying to select only first `.child` parent element that is child of `#owner .parent`?

Comment: Expected result is in comments:
4 x div.child.one (four divs children of div.parent.one)

Comment: Do you mean without including the children, that is `<div class="parent two">            <!-- parent lvl 2 -->
            <div class="child two"></div>     <!-- child lvl 2 -->
            <div class="child two"></div>
            <div class="child two"></div>
          </div>` within resulting collection?

Comment: Can you include expected `html` result returned by selection at Question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@kkris1983
This CSS selector will only apply to .child that is not nested in other .child

```
.child:not(.child .child)
```

For your more complicated case with .parent:

```
.parent>.child:not(.parent>.child .parent>.child)
```

This way you can make a selector only for the first occurrence of descendants.
Works for any level of nesting and intermediate tags.
https://codepen.io/doc_ss/pen/xxyYMaP

```js
var children = document.querySelectorAll('.child:not(.child .child)');
document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = "The number of descendants of only the first level found: "+children.length;
```

```css
#owner .parent > .child {
  background: blue;
}
#owner .child:not(.child .child) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="owner">
  <!-- ...other parent elements -->
    <div class="parent one">                <!-- parent lvl 1 -->
      <div class="child one">1               <!-- child lvl 1 -->
        <!-- ...some other  elements -->
          <div class="parent two">            <!-- parent lvl 2 -->
            <div class="child two">1.1</div>     <!-- child lvl 2 -->
            <div class="child two">1.2</div>
            <div class="child two">1.3</div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="child one">2</div> 
      <div class="child one">3</div> 
      <div class="child one">4</div> 
    </div>
  <div id="count"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use this:

```
#owner > .parent  > .child
```

With the `>` you can specify the direct children from the parent element.

Comment: I wrote important note: we do not know how deep div.parent.one is in #owner

Comment: You can only select it with a specific [tag:css] selector. Ex: `#owner div div div > .parent  > .child
`

Comment: so it is not possible without specifying direct children modifier ?

Comment: No, it is not possible. The only alternative is to select all children. But that not what you want.

Comment: @kkris1983 If this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: the answer is "No, it is not possible" so I promoted it. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Try this. you used outerdiv name also parent change the outer div name

```js
var el = document.getElementById("owner");

parent = document.querySelector('.parents');
children = parent.children;
console.info(children);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="owner">
  <div class="parents one">                <!-- parent lvl 1 -->
    <div class="child one">               <!-- child lvl 1 -->
      <div class="parent two">            <!-- parent lvl 2 -->
        <div class="child two"></div>     <!-- child lvl 2 -->
        <div class="child two"></div>
        <div class="child two"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="child one"></div> 
    <div class="child one"></div> 
    <div class="child one"></div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: without using jquery

Comment: @kkris1983 YES in above code didn't use jquery. only using javascript.

Comment: still result expected is
<div class="child one">
<div class="child one">
<div class="child one">
<div class="child one">
and not the one provided with your code

Comment: @kkris1983 now check my answer. I will change my answer for your expectation.

Comment: in description there is a note "Important: class name "one" and "two" is only for visual purposes - it does not exist. " - we do not have "one" or "two" classes. Fralec - user above states that it is impossible to do so,
any comments ?

Comment: @kkris1983 now check it.